# Problemas com o SaveDialog e função de saída do Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Galera, é o seguinte:
Estou fazendo um bloco de notas no C# a fins didáticos e me deparo com um erro que não conseguir enxergar faz 2 dias a sua causa. Sempre que eu vou salvar um arquivo de txt ele abre a janela para eu escolher onde quero salvar o arquivo, até aí tudo bem. Só que quando eu aperto em salvar, ele não encerra a aplicação, ele pergunta mais uma vez se eu quero salvar o arquivo.

Quando eu aperto o ALT+F4 (clico em sair) ele pergunta se quero salvar o arquivo, seja eu clicando em *sim* ou em *não* ele volta perguntar a mesma coisa de novo, só na segunda vez que ele ou salva e fecha ou simplesmente encerra a aplicação. Segue o código:

```
private void SalvarClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Arquivo texto | *.txt";
        sfd.ShowDialog();

           if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sfd.FileName) == false)
           {
               try
               {
                   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
                   {
                       writer.Write(JanelaDeTxt.Text);
                       writer.Flush();
                      //Application.Exit();
                       this.Close();
                   }
               }
               catch(Exception ex)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Não foi possível salvar o arquivo. Erro: [0]", ex.Message), "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                  
               }

           }

    }
```

função de sair

```
private void sairToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.JanelaDeTxt.Text))
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Deseja salvar arquivo?", "Sair do programa", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {                  
                SalvarClick(sender, e);
            }
            else if(result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                Application.Exit(); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Faça uma pesquisa no form procurando por `SalvarClick` e depois procurando por `sairToolStripMenuItem_Click` e adicione à pergunta todos os locais onde essas duas funções são usadas.

Comment: Além disso que o @PedroGaspar disse, tem várias coisas bem esquisitas e não deveria ser assim nesse código. Estou falando porque está usando para fins didáticos e imagino que gostaria de receber esse *feedback*. Não vou dizer o que porque são várias coisas e a pergunta também não é sobre isso, mas fica a dica que está aprendendo fazer algo errado, ainda que funcione (algumas coisas talvez sejam só questão de estilo ultrapassado).